# Java index name

Tags: java

```
String nameOfTools = "";

  for( int index = 0; index < userToolType; index++ )
  {
     nameOfTools = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter name of tool " + ( index + 1 ) );

     //check blank
     if ( nameOfTools.equalsIgnoreCase("") )
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered blank");
        System.exit( 0 );
     }

  }
  //Ask the number to buy for each tool
  String numberOfTools;
  double toolsNumber = 0;
  String amountOfTools;
  double moneyForTools;
  double totalMoneyToPay = 0;
  for ( int index = 0; index < userToolType; index++ )
  {
     numberOfTools = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "How many you need to buy " + ( index + 1 ) );
     toolsNumber = Double.parseDouble( numberOfTools );
```

I want the dialog to show "How many you need to by (a tool's name)" not index number how can I do this?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to store your tools in an array, because at the moment it appears you are overwriting `nameOfTools`.

Comment: Have an array of the names and use `array[index]`

Comment: @주성호 please consider accepting one of the answers you get, you've asked 3 questions today so far and haven't accepted any of them!

Comment: Please learn Java, e.g. read [The Java™ Tutorials - Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need then to create an `ArrayList<String>` to store the names of tools, something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> toolsNames = new ArrayList<String>(); // to take all names
for( int index = 0; index < userToolType; index++ ){
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter name of tool " + ( index + 1 ) );
     if ( input.equals("") ){ //check blank
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered blank");
          System.exit( 0 );
     }
     toolsNames.add(input); // if it's not blank
}
//Ask the number to buy for each tool
String numberOfTools;
double toolsNumber = 0;
String amountOfTools;
double moneyForTools;
double totalMoneyToPay = 0;
for ( int index = 0; index < userToolType; index++ ){
       numberOfTools = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "How many you need to buy from " + toolsNames.get(index));
       toolsNumber = Double.parseDouble( numberOfTools );
}
```